# What is `null false` in mutations graphQL rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

```rb
module Mutations
  class BaseMutation < GraphQL::Schema::Mutation
    null false # <---- what is this?
  end
end
```

In a lot of classes, I see this function `null(false)` or `null(true)` but I don't find any information about this in the rails graphql docs.

Answer (score 2):

It lets you make the resolver (or mutation) nullable/non-nullable. Documented [here](https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/2.0.6/GraphQL/Schema/Resolver.html#null-class_method) (note that `GraphQL::Schema::Mutation` inherits from `GraphQL::Schema::Resolver` since `Mutation` is a type of `Resolver`):

> `.null(allow_null = nil) ⇒ Object`
>
> If `true` (default), then the return type for this resolver will be nullable. If `false`, then the return type is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, it's used to indicate whether the payload object (which is auto-generated if you extend `GraphQL::Schema::Mutation`) [is nullable](https://graphql-ruby.org/mutations/mutation_classes.html).

If it's set to `null: true`, then the mutation may return no results at all rather than the payload object.

If you have a resolver named `CreateMessageResolver` and a mutation class named `MessageResolverType` with `null: true`, then the [generated schema](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields) for your mutation type will look like this:

```
type Mutation {
  createMessage(): CreateMessagePayload
}
```

If `null: false`, it will look like this:

```
type Mutation {
  createMessage(): CreateMessagePayload!
}
```